# how can i auto genrete a number in vb.net?

Tags: windows, vb.net

i want to genrete a auto number in my project....

i used vb .net 2008 and SQl server 2005 as backend ??

i want to create a serial no that is like **abc/2010/01.**.In this..

1. the **abc** is same in all the serial no.
2. the **2010** is used from the *running Year*.(using date for year)
3. the **01** is a *actual serial no that can be auto genrete...*

But how can i do this ....?? 
and How can **i find max number from my serial no**.....???
how can i maintain it if i delete it then all after delete serial no will place it's place..(there is no break in serial no on delete)
??????
Please help me.....

Comment: What do you want to use this "number" for? Why can't you use a `GUID` be good enough? Are you intending to generate this on the DB or in code?

Comment: i want to generate it in code..or DB.....?if possible....

Comment: @Oded  how can i create  GUID in sql server 2005 ???

Comment: @Gulu In SQL Server You have new_id try this http://goo.gl/Ho9GK Also you have  NEWSEQUENTIALID ( ) http://goo.gl/rg6D7 in SQL Server 2005

Comment: You use the [NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code snippet for generate newid
i have taken a simple label and textbox 
label will auto generate newid and textbox will insert a new record in database
take a label and textbox in your design page

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    public  static int temp;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            newcode();
        }

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=practice;Integrated Security=True;");

       con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into frmlogin(id,username) values ("+ temp+",'"+TextBox1.Text+"')", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", TextBox1.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        Label1.Text = "";
        newcode();

    }
    public void newcode()
    {
        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=practice;Integrated Security=True;");
        con1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Max(id) as empid from frmlogin", con1);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader r = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        r.Read();

        if (r["empid"].ToString() != "")
        {
            temp = int.Parse(r["empid"].ToString()) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 1;

        }

        Label1.Text= temp.ToString();
        r.Close();
        con1.Close();
    }



}
```

The main thing is that you should maintain your incremented number somewhere, In my case i have used textbox and label.

But I did rather recommend you to go for GUID or Random Number.

for GUID :

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Have Look [here](http://goo.gl/PoQu8) as well

for Random Number Generation

::: Program that uses Random type [C#] :::

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(random.Next());
        Console.WriteLine(random.Next());
    }
}

::: Output of the program :::

1592498984
1526415661
```

Try [this](http://goo.gl/MNonI)

Comment: @Gulu something like this : 6b6599c4-bfd3-4fee-a8e5-af43bff49063 !!

Comment: @Gulu I have Written code for the same, if you want it in vb try to convert C# to vb either here : http://converter.telerik.com/ or http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @Gulu If you want it simple then first code-snippet will do and it will work in windows as well, only you need to keep th value store of your sequence in some global variable,hidden attributte/label/textbox etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the serial numbers in a database table where the third component of the number is the primary key of the table as an identity field.  Any time you create a new serial number, you'd insert the current year and the static text into the table.  An easy way to do this would be to wrap that logic in a stored procedure which takes no arguments, internally inserts the current year and the text, and returns the entire serial number as a single scalar value.

Something like:

`INSERT INTO SerialNumbers (Year, Name) VALUES (year(getdate()), 'abc')`

and:

`SELECT Name + '/' + CAST(Year AS nvarchar) + '/' + CAST(ID AS nvarchar) FROM SerialNumbers WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`